# Can you assign an enum value to an enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I'm wanting to create an enum for a list of names and another enum for a list of categories that the names belong to. I saw this excellent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966102/how-to-assign-string-values-to-enums-and-use-that-value-in-a-switch) that does a great job in assigning strings to enums but what I'm wanting to do would be similar to the following:

```
public enum Name
{
    [CategoryAttribute(Category.Category1)]
    Name1,
    [CategoryAttribute(Category.Category2)]
    Name2,
    [CategoryAttribute(Category.Category3)]
    Name3
}

public enum Category
{
    Category1,
    Category2,
    Category3
}
```

And then I would use the extension they created in the post I mention above to be able to lookup the category for the current name, etc. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: As that post shows, you can create your own attribute and attach it to enum members. Is there a problem you're facing with that implementation?

Comment: @gunr2171 My main issue with the code as is, is because I have a few hundred names with the same categories so it just made sense to me to make category an enum as well and currently with this code you can only pass in a string for the category attribute

Comment: Enums are for fixed, hard-coded entries. Are you sure you enums are an appropriate use case for a list of names and categories? And can't you change your category attribute to accept an enum value rather than a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name Enum with names, Name4 is an example of member with no category attribute

```
public enum Name
{
    [Category(Category.Category1)]
    Name1,
    [Category(Category.Category2)]
    Name2,
    [Category(Category.Category3)]
    Name3,
    Name4
}

public enum Category
{
    //default value to return from GetCategory if no Category is assigned
    None,

    Category1,
    Category2,
    Category3
}

public class CategoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public CategoryAttribute(Category cat)
    {
        Category = cat;
    }
}
```

The value passed in the e parameter is a value of the enum's underlying type, in this case int. In order to get the attribute assigned, we first need to get the name associated with the int, and then search for attributes using the name.

```
public static class NameMethods
{
    public static Category GetCategory(this Name e)
    {
        var name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Name), e);
        var  member = e.GetType().GetMember(name).FirstOrDefault();
        var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(CategoryAttribute)) as CategoryAttribute;

        return attr?.Category ?? Category.None;
    }
}
```

Running the Code with the four different categories

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Name.Name1.GetCategory(); //Category1
        var result1 = Name.Name2.GetCategory(); //Category2
        var result2 = Name.Name3.GetCategory(); //Category3
        var result3 = Name.Name4.GetCategory(); //None
    }
}
```

If you want to go the other way and get an List of Names that have been assigned to a particular category, you can use this method. Note that this code only allows one category to be assigned to each name.

```
public static List<Name> GetNames(Category category)
{
    //Find all Members of Name Enum Type that have a categoryAttribute with the Category property assigned to the category parameter.
    var members = typeof(Name).GetMembers().ToList();
    var result = new List<Name>();
    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        //get attributes for member
        var categoryAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member, typeof(CategoryAttribute)) as CategoryAttribute;
        if (categoryAttribute != null && categoryAttribute.Category == category)
        {
            //use the member name to get an instance of enumerated type.
            Enum.TryParse(member.Name, out Name name);
            result.Add(name);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is great code. I was wondering if you know if it is possible to do the reverse and pass in the category to get a list of names with that category

Comment: @DarthVegan added method to get list of names by category

Answer (score 0):

When you create your own attribute, but instead of passing down a string, you can pass a `Category enum` itself. See my implementation below:

```
public enum Category
{
    Category1,
    Category2,
    Category3
}

public enum Name
{
    [Category(Category.Category1)]
    Name1,

    [Category(Category.Category2)]
    Name2,

    [Category(Category.Category3)]
    Name3
}

public class CategoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Category category;

    public CategoryAttribute(Category category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }
}

public static class Extentions
{
    public static Category GetCategory(this Name obj)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var attr = (CategoryAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type.GetType(), typeof(CategoryAttribute));
        return attr.category;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the first parameter to Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type.GetType(), typeof(CategoryAttribute)) is incorrect. We already have the type in the previous line. But I think we actually need to get the member name. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of care, you can give the integer values of each enum a specific meaning;

```cs
public enum Name
{
    // Category 1
    Name1 = (int)Category.Category1,
    Name2,
    Name3,

    // Category 2
    Name4 = (int)Category.Category2,
    ...
}

public enum Category {
    Category1 = 1000,
    Category2 = 2000,
}

public Category GetCategory(Name name) => (Category)((int)name - ((int)name % 1000));
```